# Refactoring AngularFire Code from 0.7.x to 1.0.0

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm having a problem refactoring some code from an old (0.7.1) [AngularFire tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-firebase-data-relationships) to the latest version of AngularFire.

I realise a bunch of things have been deprecated since, like the `$firebase` service, and we're now using `$firebaseArray` and `$firebaseObject` in its place.

I've changed all my `$firebase` services to `$firebaseObject`s, but I'm still having some trouble with the code.

I'm getting an error (`TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object.getItemsForCurrentUser (main.controller.js:83`) on this line:

```
return users.$child(currentUser + '/items/');
```

I've tried to change `$child()` to `child()`, with no luck.

Can anyone help explain what I'm doing wrong, or help point me to any resources which might give me a better understanding of migrating to AngularFire 1.0.0? I've had a look at the migration guide, but I'm still finding it tough to understand what's going on.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Full code below:

```
.constant('FIREBASE_URI', 'https://fb-relations.firebaseio.com/')

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'ItemsService', 'UsersService', function($scope, ItemsService, UsersService) {
  $scope.newItem = { name: '', description: '', count: 0 };
  $scope.currentItem = null;
  $scope.currentUser = null;
  $scope.items = null;

  $scope.users = UsersService.getUsers();

  $scope.$watch('currentUser', function() {
    UsersService.setCurrentUser($scope.currentUser);
    if ($scope.currentUser) {
      $scope.items = UsersService.getItemsForCurrentUser();
    }
  });

}])

.factory('UsersService', ['$firebaseObject', 'FIREBASE_URI', function($firebaseObject, FIREBASE_URI) {
  var usersRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI + 'users');
  var users = $firebaseObject(usersRef);
  var currentUser = null;

  var getUsers = function() {
    return users;
  };

  var getCurrentUser = function() {
    return currentUser;
  };

  var setCurrentUser = function(user) {
    currentUser = user;
  };

  var getItemsForCurrentUser = function() {
    return users.$child(currentUser + '/items/');
  };

  var addItemForCurrentUser = function(itemRef) {
    var child = users.$child(currentUser + '/items/' + itemRef.name());
    child.$set(true);
  };

  var removeItemForCurrentUser = function(itemId) {
    users.$remove(currentUser + '/items/' + itemId);
  };

  return {
    getUsers: getUsers,
    getCurrentUser: getCurrentUser,
    setCurrentUser: setCurrentUser,
    getItemsForCurrentUser: getItemsForCurrentUser,
    addItemForCurrentUser: addItemForCurrentUser,
    removeItemForCurrentUser: removeItemForCurrentUser
  };
}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too much text, but if I understand correctly you want to know how to write this AngularFire 0.7 expression in AngularFire 1.0:

```
var child = users.$child(currentUser + '/items/' + itemRef.name());
```

You do this, by dropping back to the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK for a moment:

```
var childRef = users.$ref().child(currentUser + '/items/' + itemRef.name());
```

You'll then want to create a `$firebaseObject` on that ref using:

```
var user = $firebaseObject(childRef);
```

### Update

In your comment you ask for an updated version of this AngularFire 0.7 snippet:

```
return users.$child(currentUser + '/items/');
```

In AngularFire 1.x that would be:

```
return $firebaseObject(users.$ref().child(currentUser + '/items/'))
```

Comment: I was trying to find out how to write this expression in 1.0. `return users.$child(currentUser + '/items/');`

Comment: Frank's answer is technically correct. Generally speaking, there is no reason for $child. The data for that child is already synchronized in users. Just modify it there and save. Also, [migration guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/migration-guides.html#section-0-9-x-to-1-0-0)

Comment: @Kato: but how do you bind a view to a specific object (user in this case) in an array/collect (users in this case)?

Comment: "bind" is an overloaded term here. The data for all users in the list is already synchronized from server to client. To change the remote data, one simply calls `$save()` on the appropriate record in the list.

Comment: @Kato Could you possibly explain this a little more? Very new to AngularFire. Trying to take in as many best practices as I can.